# using awk to list pids

Tags: shell, awk

I am trying to write a script that will list all of the processes running with a pid between 500 & 20000.

This is what I have so far.
`ps awux |awk '{for (i=1; i<NF; i++) {if (i>=800 && i<=17000) {print $i}}}'`

Comment: You don't need to check on each field of the `ps` output. The PID is in the second column, so if you cut the `for (i=1; i<NF; i++) ` part your command will work: `ps awux |awk '{if ($2>=800 && $2<=17000) print  }'` The [below](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/240520/66388) answer of Glenn gives you a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 4):

You're doing too much work: the PID is in the 2nd column, so you want

```
ps awux | awk 'NR==1 || (500 <= $2 && $2 <= 20000)'
```

I assume you want to see the header which is the first line.